# How to hide or change mouse cursor in new browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to create a library (plugin) for JavaScript that let users to hide mouse and change the mouse cursor with something else.

It was easy before just in CSS work with `cursor`, I found some plugins like [this](https://github.com/mdibaiee/Mickey.js), but now I visited [this website](http://www.goterratrek.com/?utm_source=AdCenter-Adgroup-USCAN-Washington-bicycle-Tours&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=AdCenter-Adgroup-USCAN-Washington-bicycle-Tours) that changed mouse courser.

**Why new browsers (or Operation systems) not supporting to change mouse cursor to a image?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the cursor to an image but it must be a specific file type. ie .ico:

```css
.cursor{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  cursor: url(http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-custom-cursor.ico), default;
}
```

```html
<body><div class="cursor"></div></body>
```

The image was from [this website](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-custom-cursor.php).

Answer (score 2):

It works. Try:

```
$('html,body').css('cursor','none');
```

OR

```
<pre>
<span style="cursor:pointer">pointer</span><br>
<span style="cursor:progress">progress</span><br>
<span style="cursor:s-resize">s-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:none">s-Hide</span><br>
</pre>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/01tu6whj/3/)